# select checkbox based on value and disable remaing in grid view

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
$(document).on('change', ".serialnotd", function () {
    var count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
    var qty = $(this).parent().children().find('.recqantity').val();
    var isssue_qty = parseInt(qty);
    var select_qty = parseInt(count);
    if (select_qty > isssue_qty) {
        alert("Selected no's. must be equal to  Qty");
    }
    if (select_qty >= isssue_qty) {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr("disabled", false);
    }
})
```

if i have (.recqantity) value = 2. Need to allow check only 2 check box not more or less of (.recqantity)value (.serialnotd) and (.recqantity) are in grid view need to check for each and every row need to done before submit (type = 'submit').
    Even tried wit each(). Still Lack of luck

Comment: I need to see your html. I don't know if you're correctly using (".recquantity"),val(), because it return you the value of the first .recquantity item and It's not clear (for me if it's what you intend). Without seeing your markup, it's hard to see if you're correctly using the traversing

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change', ".serialnotd", function () {
    var count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
    var qty = $(this).parent().children().find('.recqantity').val();
    var isssue_qty = parseInt(qty);
    var select_qty = parseInt(count);
    if (select_qty > isssue_qty) {
        alert("Selected no's. must be equal to  Qty");
    }
    if (select_qty >= isssue_qty) {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').attr("disabled", false);
    }
})


just changed 
 var count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
to
var count = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
```

Comment: Need to do for less than part.Thank you All